# Format string to HTML in C#

Tags: c#, php, html, string, formatting

So I am writing a game with Unity and I am sending players an email with all of their stats on how they played. The way I send the email is I format a string that has the html already written that replaces a specifier `$_table` to insert the data I need to send to a php script on my server that emails the user. All of this works.

I am having a problem though with sending links to images. Since I am doing this in a `C# program` I am having a hard time with `<img src ="example.com/example.png"/>` tags.

When it sends it sends it formated as `<img src=\"example.com/example.png\"/>` and doesn't show the image.

**How can I send this string correctly in C#?**

I have already tried `"` and using `@""""` to format the string.

Any and all help is appreciated.

::Edit::
Updated for code.

So in my C# code I am reading from a txt file my base html. The problem is
when I am replacing with my table which has img tags in it.

I have a Email Function SendEmail which sends a form. In the form it has a 
message parameter which is just a string. This form is sent to a php script 
which sends to the email from the form.

//Unity Code

```
public static void SendEmail(string _email, string subject, string message)
{


    if(CheckEmail(_email))//Checks if valid email form
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("from", "example@example.com");
        form.AddField("email", _email);
        form.AddField("subject", subject);
        form.AddField("message", message);

        WWW web = new WWW("http://www.example.com/_email.php", form); //Unity class for various web functions 

    }

    else
    {
        label.text = "Invalid Email";
    }
}
```

The message I am sending is a table with img links which are referenced by string variables for readability.

```
public static string GetFormatedMetricTable(){
int time = 0;
string clockIcon = "<img src = &quot;http://files.softicons.com/download/web-icons/web- grey-buttons-by-axialis-team/png/48x48/Clock.png&quot;/>";

return "<table><tr><td>" + time + clockIcon + "</td></tr></table>";
}
```

The code above is reduced for this example but only content wise.

In my php code I am using a simple mail function to send the email from my smtp server.

**The problem is in the string formatting of the double quote.**

When viewed within the html code from the email I get /" which results in the images not showing.

Desired result http://subligaming.com/example.html

Note: Using Mono .Net

Here is my php code just incase.

```
<?php
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

// $newMessage = str_replace("&quot;", '$_"', $message);
// $newerMessage = str_replace("$_", "", $newMessage);


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Subliminal Gaming <$from>\r\n";
mail($email, "$subject",
$message, $headers );
echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
?>
```

I am currently reading up on how the string literals work in php and that may be the problem but I do not know how to fix it. Any pointers?

Comment: Need more info.  What's coming through the other side?  What's the resulting HTML look like?  Are the image paths relative instead of absolute?  What does C# program have to do with tags?

Comment: Can you please share the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: the simplest thing to do is to not use double quote " inside the tag, use a single quote ' `<img src ='example.com/example.png'/>`

Comment: Where exactly is it supposed to show an image? What shows instead of the image? Can you post the code that is supposed to do this showing?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you're editing a php script programattically, and then using that to email information to a user?

Comment: Updated to help clarify my question.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing `<img src=\"example.com/example.png\"/>` ? If that is in the debugger, then you're probably chasing smoke - that is just how the IDE displays quotes. It doesn't mean that the slashes are *actually there*. If the slashes actually are there, then **only you** can tell us where they come from. C# / .NET won't add them just for fun. Your code somewhere must be doing that.

Comment: @Marc I'm grabbing that example string straight from the email so this is not in a runtime environment. From what I can tell C# is not placing in double quotes like I want but with the escape key \" even when I do literals. The php is already written and is on my server. I send a string that contains html to be sent by the php script to an email.

Comment: It seems that the problem is not from the code you have provided. Two places come to my mind: 1. The code that sends the html to the php server. 2. The php code that sends the email. Someone is changing the strings in the middle.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn I updated my post to show my php code. From what I'm reading on the php manual it could very well be how php handles literals in strings. Since I'm not echoing the string it may just send it with the \. I do not know how to prevent it from doing that or how to send as the literal.

Comment: That's not how php handles literals, something is translating that. If you were to do echo $_REQUEST['message'] in the php and the look at the results in the debugger, does it still have the problem string?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use simple quotes in the html tag

```
<img src ='example.com/example.png'/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I believe it's due to the fact that I am not printing out the string so when it is sent to php the php is interpreting it as a /' instead of just a '